# OpenGL color picking RGBA vs RGB

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, cross-platform, picking

I would like to implement color picking/selection via these three methods:

```
void ColorIndex(uint colorIndex)
{
    glColor4ubv((GLubyte *)&colorIndex);
}

void ColorIndices(vector<uint> &colorIndices)
{
    GLubyte *colorPtr = (GLubyte *)&colorIndices[0];
    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, colorPtr);
}

void ReadSelectedIndices(int x, int y, int width, int height, uint *selectedIndices)
{
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, selectedIndices);
}
```

They basically packs unsigned integer (32 bit) into 4 bytes R, G, B, A. It is simple and very fast compared to GL_SELECT.

Problem is that it sometimes does not work. It does not work for me on Windows with NVIDIA 9800 graphics card. It works for me on ATI Radeon 4670 in Mac/Windows.

I was thinking that problem is in alpha channel so I tried this implementation:

```
union RgbColor
{
    GLuint colorIndex : 24;
    GLubyte components[3];
    struct
    {
        GLubyte r;
        GLubyte g;
        GLubyte b;
    };
};

void ColorIndex(uint colorIndex)
{
    RgbColor color;
    color.colorIndex = colorIndex;
    glColor3ubv(color.components);
}

vector<GLubyte> colorComponents;

void ColorIndices(vector<uint> &colorIndices)
{
    colorComponents.clear();

    for (uint i = 0; i < colorIndices.size(); i++)
    {
        RgbColor color;
        color.colorIndex = colorIndices[i];

        colorComponents.push_back(color.components[0]);
        colorComponents.push_back(color.components[1]);
        colorComponents.push_back(color.components[2]);
    }

    GLubyte *colorPtr = (GLubyte *)&colorComponents[0];
    glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, colorPtr);
}

const uint kMaxSelectedIndicesCount = 2000 * 2000;  // max width * max height resolution

GLubyte colorBuffer[kMaxSelectedIndicesCount * 3];

void ReadSelectedIndices(int x, int y, int width, int height, uint *selectedIndices)
{
    uint count = (uint)width * (uint)height;

    memset(colorBuffer, 0, count * 3);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, colorBuffer);
    GetGLError();

    for (uint i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        RgbColor color;
        color.components[0] = colorBuffer[i * 3 + 0];
        color.components[1] = colorBuffer[i * 3 + 1];
        color.components[2] = colorBuffer[i * 3 + 2];

        selectedIndices[i] = color.colorIndex;
    }
}
```

Now on both graphics cards and OSes selection works, but sometimes bad vertices are selected (outside of selection rectangle).

How this can happen? Is there some better way to implement color picking, that is robust and always correct on various graphics cards?